# AsyncStorage does not save in between app reloads with expo (TS/React Native)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-context, asyncstorage

I have a context which stores the state for a `theme` variable in my app.
Initially it is set to `empty`.

*AppSettingsContext.tsx*

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { AppSettingsContextStruct, Themes } from "../../types";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const fetchThemeFromStorage = async () => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem("THEME")
    .then((value) => {
        if (value === `"LIGHT"`) {
            return Themes.LIGHT;
        };
        if (value === `"DARK"`) {
            return Themes.DARK;
        };
        if (value === `"empty"` || "empty") {
            return Themes.EMPTY;
        };
        
        })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return Themes.LIGHT;
    });
};

const defaultVal: AppSettingsContextStruct = {
    theme: Themes.EMPTY,
    setTheme: () => {},
}

type CtxProps = {
    children: JSX.Element
}

const AppSettingsContext = createContext(defaultVal);

const AppSettingsContextProvider:React.FC<CtxProps> = (props) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Themes>(Themes.EMPTY);

    useEffect(() => {
        const asyncWrap = async () => {
            const storageTheme = await fetchThemeFromStorage();
            return {
                theme: storageTheme,
            }
        }
        asyncWrap().then((value) => {
            console.log("asyncWrap ran:", value)
            if (value.theme === JSON.stringify(Themes.EMPTY)) {
                setTheme(Themes.LIGHT);
            };
        })

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("THEME", JSON.stringify(theme)).then(() => {
                console.log(" > ASYNC STORAGE UPDATED THEME ->", theme)
            });
    },[theme]);

    return (
        <AppSettingsContext.Provider value={{theme,setTheme}}>
            {props.children}
        </AppSettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export {AppSettingsContext, AppSettingsContextProvider}
```

Which wraps my entire app
*App.tsx*

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import RootNavigator from './navigator/RootNavigator';
import {UserContextProvider} from "./components/contexts/UserContext"
import {AppSettingsContextProvider} from "./components/contexts/AppSettingsContext"

export default function App() {
      return ( 
        <UserContextProvider>
          <AppSettingsContextProvider> 
            <NavigationContainer>
              <RootNavigator />
            </NavigationContainer>
          </AppSettingsContextProvider>
        </UserContextProvider>
      );
}
```

This is then used within a hook

*useAppSettingsContext.ts*

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { AppSettingsContext } from "../components/contexts/AppSettingsContext"

export const useAppSettingsContext = () => {
    const context = useContext(AppSettingsContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error("useUserContext was used outside of its Provider");
    }
    return context
}
```

Then I have a component to set the value of *theme*:

*SettingsToggleComponent.tsx*

```
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native"
import { useAppSettingsContext } from '../../hooks/useAppSettingsContext';
import { Themes } from '../../types';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
type Props = {
    id: string;
    settingName: string;
    iconName: string;
    sendActionLower: Function;
};


const SettingsToggleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ( {id, settingName, sendActionLower} ) => {
    const {
        theme, setTheme
    } = useAppSettingsContext();
    const [isLight, setIsLight] = useState<boolean>(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (theme === Themes.LIGHT) {
            setIsLight(true);
        } else if (theme === Themes.DARK) {
            setIsLight(false);
        } else {
            setIsLight(false);
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() => {
            //changing asyncStorage will cause rerender at root? -> false
            if (theme === Themes.LIGHT) {
                setIsLight(false)
                setTheme(Themes.DARK)
            } else {
                setIsLight(true)
                setTheme(Themes.LIGHT)
            }

        }}>
            <View style={styles.settingLayout}>
            {/* Make sure that the possible names for the icons are used instead of random icon names */}
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="theme-light-dark" size={24} color="#5a5a5a" />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.textContainerLayout}>
                        <Text style={styles.settingName}>{settingName}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.arrowSettingValueContainer}>
                            {
                                isLight?
                                <Ionicons name="ios-sunny-sharp" size={24} color="#5A5A5A" />
                                : <Ionicons name="ios-moon-sharp" size={24} color="#5A5A5A" />
                            }
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

When I switch the theme using the component the theme updates in AsyncStorage correctly but when i reload the app from within the terminal or by restarting the expo app, AsyncStorage no longer holds the theme that was previously set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a typo that I had written within `AppSettingsContextProvider`, I had been comparing the return value of `asyncWrap` to the stringified version of the theme.

The code should've been:

```
        asyncWrap().then((value) => {
            if (value.theme === Themes.EMPTY) {
                setTheme(Themes.LIGHT);
            } else {
                setTheme(value.theme);
            }
        })
```

This will mean that the default value of empty will be overridden once the stored value was fetched, as the default value of `theme` will have already been set.